# How to check date string is entered with year in 4-digit format? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to create a function that will check if a date string has been entered with the year in a 4-digit format, e.g. 1-1-45 would return 0, 1-1-2045 would return 1.

Can someone give me a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is 1-1-45 the only input format needs validation?

Comment: Why are you letting people enter freetext dates? You shouldn't be accepting arbitrary strings in the first place. Use a calendar control or drop-downs, then you can use a sensible format like `YYYYMMDD`. If you allow `1-4-2045` is that January 4th or April 1st?

Comment: Ok, alternatively, can you give me a way to check if a date is entered in the format YYYY-MM-DD?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
where right(val, 4) like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports `ISNUMERIC()`

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(RIGHT('1-1-2045', 4))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11814)

*Why not use date picker or any other controls that allows you to choose date?*

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I suggested a date picker but the users want to be able to enter the date as text... but have it only accept 4-digit years.

Comment: J W, Your query will return 1 for many formats without a four-digit year. For example, it accepts '1-1-045' and '3.4.12'